# Values update of the column

Tags: python-3.x

$ how can i change the values of the test_score column?

```
raw_data = {'student_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 
          'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 
          'Riani',   'Ali'], 
'test_score': [76.0, 88, 84, 6.7, 53.98, 96, 64, 91, 77, 73, 52, 
np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student_name','test_score'])
    for row in df['test_score']:
        if  row > 50:
            data["test_score"][row] = "Pass"
        else:
            print("fail")
df
```

when i run the program values in the dataframe doesn't update

```
error
File "<ipython-input-34-dc0786ed1a6e>", line 3
        data["test_score"][row] = "PAss"
           ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: there has to be an indent after an if statement. `data["test_score"][row] = "Pass"` isn't indented properly

Comment: bro indent error have resolved but values doesn't update in dataframe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` isn't defined in the code either so that will through an error but if what you are trying to do is create a column denoting whether a student passed or failed the test a much faster way to do it is to use the `numpy.where()` function. Its much faster than looping through the data frame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'student_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 
          'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 
          'Riani',   'Ali'], 
'test_score': [76.0, 88, 84, 6.7, 53.98, 96, 64, 91, 77, 73, 52, 
np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student_name','test_score'])

df['test_score'] = np.where(df['test_score'] > 50, 'Pass', 'Fail')
print(df)
```

which gives this output

```
   student_name test_score
0        Miller       Pass
1      Jacobson       Pass
2           Ali       Pass
3        Milner       Fail
4         Cooze       Pass
5         Jacon       Pass
6        Ryaner       Pass
7          Sone       Pass
8         Sloan       Pass
9         Piger       Pass
10        Riani       Pass
11          Ali       Fail
```

If you don't want to overwrite the column then just create a new one like this 
`df['pass_fail'] = np.where(df['test_score'] > 50, 'Pass', 'Fail')`